# MemoryLeak - http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/fl_any_projection/index.html

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, memory

Attention ESRI - Loading http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/fl_any_projection/index.html inside of [sIEve](https://ieleak.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ieleak) shows a significant amount of memory loss each time the page loads (+10MB).  Any workarounds?

Comment: Posted on ArcGIS forum here (and poster mentions that Esri support has been contacted): http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/79227-Memory-Leaks-IE8

Comment: I also posted a similar issue with OL to https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/900

Comment: Resource Monitor does not show an loss of memory in IE8 so perhaps sIEve cannot be trusted.  Resource Monitor does show a a leak in *CHROME ONLY* when visiting this sample: http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/renderer_feature_layer_function_animate/